# Skipping statements inside an IfStatements

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, libtooling

I have created an `if(isa<IfStmt>(s))` and `if(isa<ReturnStmt>(s))` which prints something if found. I have created this simple c++ codes which contains return statement inside an if statement

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int a = atoi(argv[1]);
  if(a == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return 10;
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to skip/ignore the **return statement** inside an **if else statement** ?

Comment: You mean you want a clang ast query which only matches return statements which aren't within if blocks?

Comment: @dutow yes exactly. please pardon my english as I am bad at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clang-query test.cpp --`

```
match returnStmt(unless(hasAncestor(ifStmt()))
```

To solve problems like this, the [AST matcher's reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) and clang's `-ast-dump` [parameter](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html) are your friends. And also `clang-query` itself, as it accepts mostly the same DSL as `clang`'s C++ API.